# Sets with structure

Tags: category-theory

I am currently studying Arbib's "Arrows, structures, and functors: the categorical imperative". He states that *structure is abstract* property is the following:

> Given an isomorphism of sets, $f:X\to Y$, and if $t$ belongs in the structure of $Y$ there exists a unique $s$ in the structure of $X$ with 
>   $$
> f:(X,s)\to (Y,t)
> $$ 
>   and 
>   $$
> f^{-1}:(Y,t)\to (X,s).
> $$

To clarify the meaning of structure, for example given an arbitrary set $X$,  $\mathbf{Vect}(X)$ is the set of all ($+$, $\cdot$)  that turn $X$ into a vector space. Picking *$s$ in the structure of $X$* would amount to picking a set of operations ($+$, $\cdot$) that turns $X$ into a vector space.

My question is why we demand that *given $t$ in the structure of $Y$ that there be a unique $s$ in the structure of $X$* and not the (maybe?) more straightforward: *given an $s$ in the structure of $X$ that there be a unique $t$ in the structure of $Y$*...

Comment: In the end, it amounts to the same thing in this case, but in general, mathematicians often find it more appealing when structure is _pulled back_ along a function rather than _pushed forward_. If I had to read the mind of the author, that would be my guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "given an $s$ in the structure $X$, there must be a unique $t$ in the structure $Y$" does not require $f$ be an isomorphism. That's just the property of any function. We *need* the uniqueness of $s$, or $t$ could pull back to a bunch of structures that map to $t$.